# Multi filter mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create a filter that is based on attributes.
It is envisaged that this is a multi-filter.

My table looks like this:

```
product_id  attribute_id  attribute_option_id
----------  ------------  -------------------
4           16            51
4           13            28
5           16            51
6           16            51
```

If you choose attribute_option_id 51 then i will get product_id 4, 5 and 6.
When i choose the attribute_option_id(s) 51 and 28 i wil get the product_id(s) 4, 5 and 6.
This a result that don't want. In this case i would only want product_id 4.
Now I thought that I could solve this by this line

```
WHERE product_attribute.Attribute_option_id IN ('51 ', '28')
```

But it was anticipated that this is not the solution.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

```
select a.product_id from (
  select product_id, count(*) as cnt 
  from mytable
  where attribute_option_id in (51, 28)
  group by product_id having count(*) =2) a
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse. I get this error message when i try it: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: +1 but you don't need a subselect. (If you didn't want to return `COUNT(*)`, you could just omit it from the `SELECT` clause.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  product_id IN (SELECT a.product_id 
                      FROM   mytable a 
                             INNER JOIN mytable b 
                               ON a.product_id = b.product_id 
                      WHERE  a.attribute_option_id = '51' 
                             AND b.attribute_option_id = '28')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This could be a solution. But the problem is that it can be more then 2 filter attribute options ids. This means that i have to make for each attribute option id a new innner join?